# How does Phonegap / Cordova handle bandwidth throttling, timeout, and retries in file upload requests?

Tags: ios, cordova, mobile, 3g, 3g-network

I've built a few native iPhone applications that required uploading large/hirez image files to a remote server. I've found that on 3g networks a request can get blocked/dropped if it uses too much bandwidth in a certain amount of time. I believe that to be about 1mb/min

reference: [Max payload size for http request and response, iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988375/max-payload-size-for-http-request-and-response-iphone/1988388#1988388)

How is this being handled in Phonegap / Cordova's API call: FileTransfer.upload()?

Along the same lines, I've run into trouble with connections retrying multiple times after failure. By default is there any connection retry going on behind the scenes?... or will the error callback fire on first connection failure?

Also! Is there a way to set the timeout of the request from the client side?